# Batch script, search string from log file

Tags: string, batch-file, search, newline

How can i search for a string in log file which contains both CR CRLF using batch command?
I'm trying to search "Updating release" and it will print out "to"

Here is my code:

```
@ECHO OFF

set buildlog="log"
SET REVISION=
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%A IN (`type "%buildlog%"`) DO IF "%%~A"=="Updating" IF "%%~B"=="release" SET REVISION="%%~C"
ECHO %REVISION%
```

log file -->

[image]

**Above code work if the log file is -->**

[image]

How can search something without changing CR to CRLF?

Comment: What about with `"usebackq tokens=4-6* delims=. "` (dot and space)?

Comment: ^^ that didn't work..

Comment: I'm afraid that your _didn't work_ brings no added value. I have created a test file repeating three   lines you have provided and with increasing number. Then next command `for /F "tokens=1-26" %A in ('type "28611316.txt"') do @echo %D %E %F` gives _Release To 28_    and so on without any problem. Input filtered as follows `'type "D:\VB_scripts\SO\filesOut\28611316.txt"^|find "Release"'` gives the same (satisfactory) results.